# Macbook Pro screen keeps randomly going black after login, weird issues

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, sleep-wake, nvram

A couple days ago while I was using my 15 inch Macbook Pro 2015 Retina Display laptop (got it brand new 2-3 months ago, running latest version of Sierra), the screen flashed black a few times, and then completely went to sleep on its own while I was in the middle of something. I couldn't get it to wake up, so I had to force restart it. After that, I couldn't get it to turn back on unless it was connected to a power source. As soon as I would turn it back on and login, the screen would go black again. Even just opening finder or safari or sitting on the desktop would make it go black.

I looked online and attempted resetting the SMC and PRAM several, several, several times. Sometimes, I would login and the screen would be completely distorted and discolored. I attempted logging in via the Guest account, and browsed Safari for 2+ hours just fine, but as soon as I went back to my user account the problem started again. I rebooted and ran the disk utilities and even re-installed Mac OS completely. I still have no luck, and now, sometimes when I turn it on, the "startup chime" will play over and over again every 2 seconds like it's trying to start up but can't.

I'm not sure what to do at this point as I've already tried a fresh install of Mac OS. Next, I was thinking of erasing my drives but before I do that I want to see if there's anything else I can do. I even changed all of my system settings to not dim the screen display and to never go to sleep because the screen was randomly dimming at times.

Any thoughts?

P.S. I'm currently typing this on the Macbook after booting it with command+r and clicking on "safari help", again it works fine in when logged in as Guest too, it's only after I login to my user account that this happens. Sometimes it's immediate, sometimes it takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got into the Apple store today to see if someone could take a look at the problem. I waited about an hour and a half and during that time I was able to use my Macbook just fine. I found that if I left the mouse idle for more than about 10 seconds that the display would shut off. However, while playing a graphics intensive game like League of Legends, it was just fine, so that's what I did for an hour and a half.

When I brought it in I was able to reproduce the problem immediately by just leaving it idle for a few seconds. They ran their diagnostic test and found that something failed with the display's backlight sensor I guess. They sent it in and it was covered under warranty.

So looks like back to my slow 4gb RAM Acer laptop for 3-5 days while they fix it! I've only had it for around 90 days so I'm not sure if it's just a defect or something I did. I haven't dropped it or spilled anything on it. Who knows.

Comment: I have the same issue with my MBP 2018 ,  will you please suggest me what can I do now ?